# Word for 'energy-less-ness'

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a single word that can connote the concept of (or something similar to) "energy-less-ness"? (this, as far as I can tell, is not a word)

It's meant to be used in the context of burnout. When an employee is losing energy for "working too much", he/she is experiencing feelings of... *[energyless-ness]*.

Thanks for sharing the richness of your vocabulary. :)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48016/8019

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[Exhaustion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhaustion?show=0&t=1394835378)**: the state of being exhausted.

Where *exhausted* is the state of having used all of someone's mental or physical energy : to be tired out or worn out (someone) *completely*; to be *completely* used up.

**Exhaustion** has the meaning of being completely "energyless", whereas words like *lethargy* and *fatigue* more closely mean "having little energy".

Comment: Jinx, owe me a coke. ;)

Comment: You're four minutes late this time. :)

Answer (score 12):

Depending on the context, "Lethargy" may be a fit.

http://m.dictionary.com/definition/lethargy

Similarly there is: "sluggishness", "listlessness", "lassitude" and "fatigue".

Surely one of these will fit.

UPDATE:

In light of clarifications, **FATIGUE** is the word you seek.

http://m.dictionary.com/definition/fatigue

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I added the usage context to the question. Do you think *lethargy* fits that?

Comment: In this case, fatigue is your best fit.

Comment: @Chris I think "fatigue" might fit that.. depends if they are without energy due to too much work or not

Comment: @d'alar'cop Yes, the former. Due to too much work. I shall edit the question, I guess.

Comment: @Chris Then I would definitely say that "fatigue" works for your need.

Answer (score 10):

To emphasize the lack of energy, use **exhaustion.** To emphasize the effort that led to exhaustion, use **fatigue.** For a more informal term, you can use **burnout.**

Answer (score 5):

If someone is *losing energy* that would imply that they do have some energy remaining. However if you want to convey total exhaustion, you could use the word, "spent".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[*drained*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drained) would be suitable.

> to exhaust physically or emotionally < feeling drained at the end of a long workday >

Answer (score 3):

How about languor? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/languor

1. lack of energy or vitality; sluggishness.
2. lack of spirit or interest; listlessness; stagnation.
3. physical weakness or faintness.
4. emotional softness or tenderness.

Answer (score 3):

You could try *[torpor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/torpor)*:-

> n.
>
> 1. sluggish inactivity or inertia.
> 2. lethargic indifference; apathy.
> 3. a state of suspended physical powers and activities.
> 4. dormancy, as of a hibernating animal.

or the adjective *[torpid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/torpid)*:-

> adjective
>
> 1. inactive or sluggish.
> 2. slow; dull; apathetic; lethargic.
> 3. dormant, as a hibernating or estivating animal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the way you intend to use the word "energyless-ness", but here are some words:--

powerlessness, inactivity, inertness, stagnancy, sluggishness, listlessness, stationariness, stillness, motionlessness, lethargy... ARSENAL OF WORDS EMPTIED.

Comment: Thesaurus (from the- plus -saur): The oracular god-lizard of the ancient logophile culture. Said to be somewhat verbose in its pronouncements.

Comment: not inertness. Inertness only says an objects is not moving. It doesn't say anything about potential energy.

Comment: And the dearth of potential energy is precisely what the questioner  seeks.

Answer (score 0):

I like lethargic but that was already taken so the next thing that comes to mind is **sloth**.

> reluctance to work or make an effort; laziness.

Comment: Laziness is a lack of motivation, not a lack of energy.

Comment: sloth means lazy, you simply don't want to do it. But you still could be energetic.

Answer (score -1):

If the lack of energy comes from a place of boredom, *ennui* is also a fantastic fit.

Comment: *ennui* has absolutely nothing to do with burnout.