# How to frame a sentence which means that someone has passed the day idly lying back on the couch?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to frame a sentence in English which means that someone has passed the whole day lying back simply on the couch idly and doing nothing. But I cant frame that in an appropriate manner.

Comment: You seem to have framed it fine just then.

Comment: Are you looking for a shorter phrase or an idiomatic expression?

Comment: No something like ' He spent the whole day lying back on the couch idly ' . But I think it can framed more beautifully or rather appropriately.

Comment: Related: [word meaning 'intending to do nothing'](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48016/8019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Andrew Leach's suggestion...

*passed the day lying on the couch*

*spent the day chillaxing on the couch*

*idled away the day on the couch*

*wasted the day on his back on the couch*

*did nothing all day on the couch...*

*decided to be a couch-potato all day*

..chillax is meant to be a combination of chill and relax

..couch-potato is someone who does not move from the couch, usually, but not necessarily, because they are watching television...

Comment: "potatoe"?......

Comment: @markratledge - sorry always do that in confustion with the 'potatoes' on the end of my feet - thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the word *lazed* or *lazed around*:

> Spend time in a relaxed, lazy manner:
>   *she spent the day at home, reading the papers and generally lazing around*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laze)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the idiom

> **while away** - To spend some duration of time idly

Eg: He has been **whiling away** the entire day on the couch.

Comment: Note that you sometimes see the archaic spelling "wile" here -- "wile away the hours" instead of "while away".

Answer (score 2):

You have already been given suitable answers, but for reference purposes:

to **lounge** (*verb*), is to lie, sit or stand in a relaxed or lazy way.

eg Mary spent ages *lounging* on the sofa.

Tom *lounged* idly in bed.

I have been *lounging* about all day.

(*Source*):  [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lounge)